# The number of partitions by distinct positive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $N>0$ be a natural number and let $P(N)$ denote the number of ways to write $N$ as a finite sum of $a_i$ such that the $a_i$ are strictly decreasing positive natural numbers.  There is a paper by Hardy and Ramanujan that proves that $\log(P(N))\sim\pi (N/3)^{1/2}$.  Here, the meaning of $\sim$ is that the ratio goes to $1$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.  But I would be happy with showing that the ratio (LHS/RHS) is bounded above.  Is there a way to do this without appealing to analytic number theory?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. This is the same as the number of partitions with distinct parts, right? 2. Would another way of writing what you are trying to show be $\log P(N) = O(\sqrt N)$? 3. Do you have any reason to believe that this is easier/more interesting than looking at the "normal" non-restricted partition function?

Comment: @DanielR 1. yes 2. yes 3. It arises in the analysis of the self-avoiding walks.  See, for instance, Madras and Slade.  There, the distinctness is important because of the combinatorics that occur when one decomposes a self-avoiding walk into bridges.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe it would be a good strategy to work with the very much more well-studied non-restricted partition function, for which $\log p(N)=O(\sqrt N)$, $n \to \infty$ also holds. Then the same relation follows trivially for the function that counts only distinct/odd partitions (or any restricted partitions for that matter).